# Android 6 UsageStatsManager isAppInactive() permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-appstandby

I'm using `isAppInactive()` method from `UsageStatsManager` class on Android 6 (API 23) to detect the standby state of the app I'm developing.

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) affirm that it is necessary to request `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` permission but I'm able to use that method without requesting the permission.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UsageStatsService` there is a `hasPermission` [[1]](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/usage/java/com/android/server/usage/UsageStatsService.java#L1148-L1162) method that checks if the permission `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` is granted. It is used in this methods:

- `queryEvents` [[2]](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/usage/java/com/android/server/usage/UsageStatsService.java#L1209)
- `queryConfigurations` [[3]](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/usage/java/com/android/server/usage/UsageStatsService.java#L1188)
- `queryUsageStats` [[4]](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/usage/java/com/android/server/usage/UsageStatsService.java#L1167)
- `queryAndAggregateUsageStats` (it uses the same method of `queryUsageStats`)

This is the code of `isAppInactive` [[5]](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/services/usage/java/com/android/server/usage/UsageStatsService.java#L1222-L1236), and you can see how the permission is not requested:

```
@Override
public boolean isAppInactive(String packageName, int userId) {
    try {
        userId = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().handleIncomingUser(Binder.getCallingPid(),
                Binder.getCallingUid(), userId, false, true, "isAppInactive", null);
    } catch (RemoteException re) {
        return false;
    }
    final long token = Binder.clearCallingIdentity();
    try {
        return UsageStatsService.this.isAppIdleFilteredOrParoled(packageName, userId, -1);
    } finally {
        Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(token);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the message of [commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/cf76872a62075abf9008e99ca08413fb70761dc2) that adds `isAppInactive` (originally is called `isAppIdle` then it is renamed) the API should be public:

```
Add ability to get and set idle state of apps
Add am shell command to set and get idle
Add public API to check if an app is idle
```

I don't think this is a bug, but only an unclear documentation.